Dramatic slowdown of AVX2 code benchmarking sqrt, sin, cos depending on total string length - why?
Intel 2022 ICX compiler with AVX2 code generation and maximum optimisation shows a curious 30x slowdown when text string length in a printf is altered by a single character. How? Why? This is a much simplified MRE similar to the one that I posted about the same problem with MS C 17.1 AVX2 slowdown a couple of days ago. Back then I thought the problem was Microsoft specific since I had never seen it happen with ICX or GCC.
The Intel compiler seems to mostly generate code that runs at full speed (unlike MSC where about 3/4 of string lengths are in a tarpit. I found this behaviour purely by chance. It was intended to benchmark common math library functions of one variable in their float and double implementations to see which was fastest. I have trimmed it down to the bare minimum that still shows the errant behaviour. I developed it on MSC without any issues but then found that sqrt was horrifically slow on ICX. Full speed was restored by padiding the string with the right number of characters! It is much smaller and simpler than my previous MRE code.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

#define M_PI  3.141592653589793238462643383

// Sweep floats from 0 to pi in steps of pi/2^32 and compute integral
// all arguments and function evaluations finite - no denorms and no infinities

void timefun(const char* name, double (*test_fun)(double)) // was , bool verbose)
{
   // simple minded integration of test_fun for timing purposes

   uint32_t argi;
   double arg, arginc, res, sum;
   time_t start, end;
   printf("\nTiming %s\n", name);
   argi = 0;
   sum = 0.0;
   arg = 0x1.0p-100; // so that log won't object
   arginc = M_PI / (0x1.p+32 - 1.0);
   start = clock();
   do {
       res = (*test_fun)(arg);
       if (!isnan(res))        // this test for nans seems to be implicated
           sum += res;
       argi++; // sequential
       arg = argi * arginc;
       if ((argi & 0x3ffffff) == 0) printf(".");
   } while (argi);
   end = clock();
//    sum = sum / (0x1.p+32 - 1.0);  // adding this normalisation line makes it run full speed       
   printf("\ntime taken %6.2f  sum = %g\n", (float)(end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC, sum);
}

int main(void)
{                                       
    printf("printf string 0123456789ABCD\n"); // remove one character to radically alter timing behaviour on Intel 2022 ICX compiler
//   printf("prin\n"); // low water mark for misbehaviour (a 24 byte block and string that *must* end \n !
    timefun("sqrt", sqrt); 
    timefun("cos",  cos);  // this line is *essential* to the misbehaviour - I don't know why! 
    timefun("sin",  sin);  // also needed for slowdown
    return 0; 
}

That this behaviour is so similar and can now be reproduced on two completely different compilers suggests to me that the problem is either:

Coding error in the timefun routine that I have missed
A flaw in the MS VC debugging runtime environment
Hardware issue with some 12th gen Intel CPUs
Something else I haven't considered

Right now I'm inclined towards 2 or possibly 3 or perhaps a combination of both.
These are the timing results running the benchmark inside the IDE and hobbled by deleting the "D" character from the end of the string in the printf at the start of main()



test function
slow
fast
superfast (sqrt inlined)
superfast (sqrt inlined)




sqrt
397
13.2
6.3
6.4


cos
28.8
28.9
29.6
-


sin
34.9
35.0
-
-



The slowdown of sqrt is so huge that I don't see how it can arise from deleting a single character from a string literal. I'm hoping that this MRE being quicker and smaller will be also reproducible on other systems. Can anyone please explain it?
A couple of new observations arising from a mistake I made testing for the range where the slowdown is present. The terminal "\n" on the first printf is essential to the misbehaviour - without that it seems to run full speed. The block where it runs slow is 24 bytes long. I have not been able to locate another one by string padding.
I was not able to change (float) to (double) in the time computation without losing the errant behaviour entirely. It is however possible it is still there and I just didn't find the right magic length of string.
It only seems to be a problem in this instance if it is run in the MS VC debugger. Run without debugger, under Intel VTune or on a new command line it is always? full speed.
Reducing the number of routines benchmarked to 2 or 1 results in the compiler inlining the sqrt function and so doubling its speed as a result. For 3 benchmarks or more it calls __imp_sqrt in the conventional manner.
Benchmarking cos is essential to having it misbehave. I have no idea why.
I tried profiling it in VTune in the nominally failed state when run in the MS debugger and it happily ran at full speed without problems. It also seems to run OK from a command line even when it is glacially slow in the MS debugging environment.
Since I think this might possibly be a hardware glitch in the CPU the details for my system are:
Win 11 Pro
Intel 12th gen i5-12600K  6P + 4E
Family 6   Model 7   Stepping 2
ExtFam 6   ExtMod 97 Rev C0
Core speed 4.5GHz multiplier 45x (under load)

It wouldn't surprise me if it only shows up on chips made around the same time. Can anyone else reproduce this behaviour?

@chux I have tidied up the code as you suggested. Couldn't swap (float) for (double)(end-start) or the whole thing stopped misbehaving. That could implicate printf varargs logic. Eliminated bool verbose and behaviour persisted. M_PI now defined locally. Established that 24 byte range has the slowdown problem and also that it vanished if "\n" is removed!

Martin, Code still using the wrong type time_t start, end; where it should be clock_t start, end;

@njuffa thanks for trying. I'm homing in on a smaller test code but reproducibility is challenging. It almost seems like errant behaviour depends on the previous compilation or the state of the machine. Right now after reboot I can't make it fail at all (and I know this same code did fail yesterday). Single character changes to the source code string table alter behaviour (yet apart from the functions under test there are no explicit pointers in my code). One thing I did find late on Friday was that eliminating the  (redundant)  if (!isnan(res)) conditional test made it all run flat out.

@njuffa to avoid issues with system library functions I was able to make it fail using a much simpler  Horner vs Estrin fourth order polynomial evaluation so that all failing code is visible. My hunch at the time was that MS cache unfriendly coefficient table ordering was to blame(but no). However, the code under test did have a wading through treacle mode yesterday which has now spontaneously gone away. It might be relevant that the benchmark loop is exactly 4 bytes short of a cache line long.  I'll try the latest ICX version and see what difference that makes. Thanks again.
